# Powershell Setting other Attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Okay so I'm trying to figure out how to use PowerShell to write to AD in both the phone number and the other attributes:

[image]

Typically I am just using a code that will take a name and a number and apply it to the Mobile, telephone, pager etc.

```
Function AddNumberToAD
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias('UserInfo')]
        [string]$UserNameToAdd,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Alias('PhoneNumber')]
        [string]$UsersPhoneNumberToAdd
    )
    
    $user = EmailToName $UserNameToAdd
    oneEmptyLine
    
    $usersRealName = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties Name
    
    $title    = 'Assign Number'
    Write-Host "Users Name: ", $usersRealName.Name
    write-Host "Username: ", $user
    Write-Host "Email: ",$UserNameToAdd
    Write-Host "Phone Number to be Added: ",$UsersPhoneNumberToAdd
    
    $question = 'Assign Phone Number as?'
    $choices  = @(
        [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Mobile Number", "Verizon Wireless Number")
        [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Telephone Number", "Teams Phone Number")
        [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Cancel", "Exit Function")
    )

    $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 2)
    if ($decision -eq 0) 
    {
        
    }
    elseif($decision -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Host "Setting user Telephone Number to Active Directory..." -ForegroundColor Green
        Set-ADUser $user -Add @{telephonenumber=$UsersPhoneNumberToAdd}
    }
    Elseif($decision -eq 2)
    {
        Return
    }           
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Invalid input recieved..." -ForegroundColor Red
```

Works just fine, however we uttilize the other function and typically match the mobile number to the number:
[image]

(ignore the 3, this is just an example)

I would like to write the script so it would insert the mobile number into the mobile other attribute but i can not figure out how to. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have tried -OtherAttribute but I cant seem to make it work.

Tried just about everything that I can think of. Just trying to get it to replicate into the other column,

Telephone: [image]

Comment: The parameter you're looking for is `-MobilePhone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you can use to set the user's mobile phone is [`-MobilePhone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-mobilephone):

```bash
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Set-ADUser $user -MobilePhone $UsersPhoneNumberToAdd
}
```

If you want to use [`-Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-add) to include the user's mobile (Other) then you need to look at the attribute's **ldapDisplayName**, for instance, for the mobile (Primary) and mobile (Other) you can use [`mobile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-mobile) and [`otherMobile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-othermobile).

For your current function however if you want to set both attributes in one go then you will need to add a new parameter to accept both values, I'm using `$ParameterForMobile` and `$ParameterForOtherMobile` as a placeholder in this case.

```
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Set-ADUser $user -Add @{
        mobile      = $ParameterForMobile
        otherMobile = $ParameterForOtherMobile
    }
}
```

Comment: Always something so easy. Thank you for your help! that worked!

Comment: @GlenNewell glad it was helpful

Comment: so that works for everything except when i try and do the telephone
if ($decision -eq 1) {
    Set-ADUser $user -Add @{
        Telephonenumber      = $ParameterForTelephone
        otherTelephonenumber = $ParameterForOtherTelephone
    }
}

Comment: @GlenNewell im not aware of a `otherTelephonenumber` attribute in Active Directory. I think you meant `otherMobile` ?

Comment: Wish i could add pictures of what i was talking about... adding one to the bottom of my post.. please hold.

Comment: ah yes @GlenNewell I see what you mean, I believe the ldapDisplayName for that attribute is `otherTelephone` (so, remove `number` from it), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adls/4cace7cb-8584-49e3-b7a9-1df5cf8470f3

Comment: yup i just found it too lol.. thanks again!